# php mssql_query() fail without any error and only when selecting a particular table

Tags: php, sql

I don't understand why this piece of code miserably fails.
The first pass of the for() loop works fine but in the second pass mssql_query() fails, no errors are reported and the program just die.

```
for($i=0; $i <2; $i++){
       $query = "SELECT * FROM Viaggio ";
       $result = mssql_query($query, $link) or die("query fallita:".msql_error());
          if( mssql_num_rows($result) ){
             while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result, MSSQL_ASSOC)){
                echo 'blablablabla' . $row[some_index] . 'blabla';
             }
          }
    }
```

I don't know why this happen, It's works with all the other tables in my database except for Viaggio.
This is the CREATE TABLE query directly from msSQL:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Viaggio](
 [codViaggio] [bigint] IDENTITY(0,1) NOT NULL,
 [data] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
 [oraArrivo]  AS ([data]+[durata]),
 [corsaExpress] [bit] NOT NULL,
 [durata] [time](7) NOT NULL,
 [fascia] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [distanza] [char](3) NOT NULL,
 [nave] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [partenza] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [arrivo] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Viaggio] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [codViaggio] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Viaggio]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Viaggio_Nave] FOREIGN KEY([nave])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Nave] ([nome])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Viaggio] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Viaggio_Nave]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Viaggio]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Viaggio_Rotta] FOREIGN KEY([partenza], [arrivo])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Rotta] ([pPartenza], [pArrivo])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Viaggio] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Viaggio_Rotta]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Viaggio]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Viaggio_Tariffa] FOREIGN KEY([fascia], [distanza])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Tariffa] ([fascia], [distanza])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Viaggio] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Viaggio_Tariffa]
GO
```

Thank you very much

[EDIT] I just tried to use mssql_free_result() but also this function crash the program.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this will do the trick but:
"SELECT * FROM Viaggio;" - notice the semicolon

Comment: @Gal - the semicolon shouldn't matter, as there is only one statement per issued query

Comment: @afftee - the question states that there is no error message

Comment: Which version of php and SQLServer do you use? What's the version `phpinfo()` reports for the mssql library?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the mssql library for each db call, but the msql library to fetch the error - is this correct?

Comment: I don't know if this is correct (I think no) but if i remove the "or die..." option nothing changes.

Comment: Why are you looping through the code twice? Try outputting mssql_num_rows($result)

Comment: The first time mssql_num_rows return 12 (the correct number of records in the table Viaggio) the second time the program hangs on mssql_query(). Nothing is returned from mssql_query() calls and the program dies.

Comment: It sounds like the mssql server is tripping out or taking too long to reply. You could try increasing the php script time limit with set_time_limit. Again, if you're looping through the same query twice then why not just query once and reuse the initial results?

Comment: Ok thank you very much, the problem was the mssql databese we HAVE to use is in a very crappy server. Adjusting the set_time_limit works well!
Obviously I need to looping through the same query but with different condition each time, I just simplified the query for posting :)

Comment: False alarm the problem is still present. :(

Comment: Either it works or it doesn't! What about if you remove the time limit completely with set_time_limit(0)?

Comment: no difference with set_time_limit(0). The problem is if I do query that doesn't return any records for example "SELECT * in Viaggio WHERE date = "date_not_present"" it works. But if the query return something I can access the data normally but if I call again mssql_query() the program suddenly stops.